# Why does Microsoft recommend not to reference entire columns in Excel formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to save a workbook with a large number of `COUNTIF()` formulas referencing another workbook, which refer to entire columns. Saving this workbook takes much longer than calculating the values the first time I enter the formulas.

On [this Microsoft Troubleshooting page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-not-responding-hangs-freezes-or-stops-working-37e7d3c9-9e84-40bf-a805-4ca6853a1ff4), the instructions say that "Formulas referencing entire columns" ... "cause performance or crashing issues". There isn't any explanation of why this is the case.

Why is this the case? Several help websites mention that the used range might be much larger than it appears. I don't think this is the cause - pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> goes to the last cell with data in it.

I am aware that I can get a performance improvement by copying the data to my current spreadsheet, to avoid an external reference. This made the two calculations (when entering the formula and when saving) take a similar amount of time. I am interested in why saving a file is slower than entering the formulas normally (with Automatic calculation), if I don't use that performance improvement.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem you are trying to solve? We cannot tell you why, necessarily, as we are not the Excel developers.

Comment: Probably because it has to load the other workbook, figure out just what is used in that column, do the calculations and then close the workbook. And then do all that again for the next calculation. And again, and again. You might find it better manually load the other workbook before this one, or to load the data another way.

Comment: Only a few functions use implicit detection of the last-used cell within the range passed. As such, with those functions you can reference entire columns with little or no detriment to calculation performance. The `IFS` family of functions fall into this category. For other functions, such as `SUMPRODUCT`, `AGGREGATE` and other array-processing function, no such implicit detection takes place. As such, using entire columns would be unwise: even if you only had data as far as row 10, for example, by referencing entire columns you would be forcing Excel to calculate over all 1,048,576 cells.

Comment: Do you mean you need to improve the Excel calculation performance? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-improving-calculation-performance